# Make dates into ordinal variables

Tags: r, date, type-conversion, lubridate, ordinal

I'm working with dates in R, and I want to convert the dates into a number that represents how many attempts it took for a participant to pass a test. Some participants took multiple attempts, and others took just one. Furthermore, some took the test years before others, so I don't care about the date, just if it was time one or time two, etc.

Here's a mock dataset:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
problem <- tibble(name = c("Britney", "Christina", "Justin", "Britney", "Britney", "Christina", "Christina", "Christina"),
                  score = c(1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 4, 2),
                  date = ymd_hms(c("2019-02-26 00:18:09", "2019-04-26 00:18:09", "2019-02-20 00:18:09", "2018-02-26 00:18:09", "2017-02-26 00:18:09", "2016-02-26 00:18:09", "2015-02-26 00:18:09", "2010-02-26 00:18:09")))
```

And here's what I want it to look like in the end:

```
solution <- tibble(name = c("Britney", "Christina", "Justin", "Britney", "Britney", "Christina", "Christina", "Christina"),
                  score = c(1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 4, 2),
                  date = ymd_hms(c("2019-02-26 00:18:09", "2019-04-26 00:18:09", "2019-02-20 00:18:09", "2018-02-26 00:18:09", "2017-02-26 00:18:09", "2016-02-26 00:18:09", "2015-02-26 00:18:09", "2010-02-26 00:18:09")),
                  order = c(3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1))

solution
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or `group_by` `name` and assign `row_number` after arranging the data by `name` and `date`

```
library(dplyr)

problem %>%
  arrange(name, date) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(order = row_number())


# A tibble: 8 x 4
# Groups:   name [3]
#   name      score date                order
#   <chr>     <dbl> <dttm>              <int>
#1 Britney       3 2017-02-26 00:18:09     1
#2 Britney       3 2018-02-26 00:18:09     2
#3 Britney       1 2019-02-26 00:18:09     3
#4 Christina     2 2010-02-26 00:18:09     1
#5 Christina     4 2015-02-26 00:18:09     2
#6 Christina     2 2016-02-26 00:18:09     3
#7 Christina     2 2019-04-26 00:18:09     4
#8 Justin        3 2019-02-20 00:18:09     1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just group by the names and take the reversed sequence, i.e.

```
library(dplyr)

problem %>% 
 group_by(name) %>% 
 mutate(order = rev(seq(n())))
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 8 x 4
> # Groups:   name [3]
>   name      score date                order
>   <chr>     <dbl> <dttm>              <int>
> 1 Britney       1 2019-02-26 00:18:09     3
> 2 Christina     2 2019-04-26 00:18:09     4
> 3 Justin        3 2019-02-20 00:18:09     1
> 4 Britney       3 2018-02-26 00:18:09     2
> 5 Britney       3 2017-02-26 00:18:09     1
> 6 Christina     2 2016-02-26 00:18:09     3
> 7 Christina     4 2015-02-26 00:18:09     2
> 8 Christina     2 2010-02-26 00:18:09     1
> ```

Answer (score 1):

We can convert to `factor` and coerce to `integer`

```
library(dplyr)
problem %>% 
    group_by(name) %>% 
    mutate(n = as.integer(factor(date)))
# A tibble: 8 x 4
# Groups:   name [3]
#  name      score date                    n
#  <chr>     <dbl> <dttm>              <int>
#1 Britney       1 2019-02-26 00:18:09     3
#2 Christina     2 2019-04-26 00:18:09     4
#3 Justin        3 2019-02-20 00:18:09     1
#4 Britney       3 2018-02-26 00:18:09     2
#5 Britney       3 2017-02-26 00:18:09     1
#6 Christina     2 2016-02-26 00:18:09     3
#7 Christina     4 2015-02-26 00:18:09     2
#8 Christina     2 2010-02-26 00:18:09     1
```

---

Or after grouping by 'name' apply `dense_rank` on the 'date'

```
problem %>% 
    group_by(name) %>%
    mutate(n = dense_rank(date))
# A tibble: 8 x 4
# Groups:   name [3]
#  name      score date                    n
#  <chr>     <dbl> <dttm>              <int>
#1 Britney       1 2019-02-26 00:18:09     3
#2 Christina     2 2019-04-26 00:18:09     4
#3 Justin        3 2019-02-20 00:18:09     1
#4 Britney       3 2018-02-26 00:18:09     2
#5 Britney       3 2017-02-26 00:18:09     1
#6 Christina     2 2016-02-26 00:18:09     3
#7 Christina     4 2015-02-26 00:18:09     2
#8 Christina     2 2010-02-26 00:18:09     1
```

NOTE: Both the solution are based on looking at the 'date' variable.  No other assumptions

Answer (score 1):

You could use `rowid` from data.table

```
library(data.table)
setDT(problem)

problem[order(date), order := rowid(name)]
```

Or you can use `frank` to rank the dates by name

```
problem[, order := frank(date), name]
```

Output of either method

```
problem
#         name score                date order
# 1:   Britney     1 2019-02-26 00:18:09     3
# 2: Christina     2 2019-04-26 00:18:09     4
# 3:    Justin     3 2019-02-20 00:18:09     1
# 4:   Britney     3 2018-02-26 00:18:09     2
# 5:   Britney     3 2017-02-26 00:18:09     1
# 6: Christina     2 2016-02-26 00:18:09     3
# 7: Christina     4 2015-02-26 00:18:09     2
# 8: Christina     2 2010-02-26 00:18:09     1
```